# ExtJS: passing arguments for event handlers

Tags: events, extjs

I'm hooking the event handler up like this:

```
Ext.getCmp('MyButton').on('click', this.onClick, null, {info: "foo"});
```

And the handler is like this:

```
function onClick(event, target, options) {
  alert(options);
}
```

I get my callback, but `options` is coming through as `undefined`. What's going wrong?  It looks to me like I'm doing what [the docs](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Manual%3aIntro%3aEvent_Handling#Custom_arguments) suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing what the docs say but you are interpreting the docs wrong. The options literal you can pass as fourth argument configures the listener (settings like delay, scope, ...). You can not use it to pass extra arguments to the listener function. That's where createDelegate comes in.

```
var a = new Ext.Button({ text: 'Click!', renderTo: Ext.getBody() });

a.on('click', function(){
    alert('click after 2 seconds!');
    console.log(arguments); // will log the strings 'Hello' and 'World'
}.createDelegate(a, ['Hello', 'World']), null, { delay: 2000 });
```

Comment: So when the docs say "you basically just add custom variables to the options object" and gives the example of setting "someProperty" and then reading it in the callback... that's just fiction? (I accept that it might be!)

Comment: I just checked the addListener docs on http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.util.Observable and can not find any reference to what you are referring to. Do you have a link?

Comment: It was the link in the question.  Which, when I look more closely at it, refers to an old version of Ext, so mystery solved.